# zu or nothing in the example

Tags: grammar, translation

I have a doubt with the use of 'zu' in the following context.

I wanted to write that the office requires the documents to be notarized only by a Notary. I tried like this:

> Die Behörde, für die ich brauche, benötigt die Dokumente nur von einem Notar beglaubigen werden.

My question is- Should I put a 'zu' in this sentence before the verb. Should it stand before beglaubigen or before werden?

Danke in Voraus

Comment: This is not a german sentence. I assume you wanted something like: "Die Behörde, für die ich die Dokumente brauche, verlangt, dass (diese | die Dokumente) von einem Notar beglaubigt werden."

Comment: Es geht auch schöner: *Meine Behörde verlangt **notariell beglaubigte** Kopien/Dokumente*.

Answer (score 2):

Hier handelt es sich leider nicht um einen korrekten deutschen Satz. Eine mögliche Formulierung mit Verwendung des Wortes **zu** wäre:

> Die Behörde verlangt, die Dokumente von einem Notar beglaubigen **zu** lassen

oder nach anderer Interpretation

> Es wird verlangt, die Dokumente, die ich für die Behörde benötige, von einem Notar beglaubigen **zu** lassen